# reduxForm: how to best dispatch an action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to submit an address form using redux form. It seems like a good way of handling the input data and validation.

I am just wondering if I can make the syntax a bit cleaner, because, frankly, trying to use connect at the same time makes the code a mess at the bottom. In my case, I want to send the address data to a Node endpoint, so I need to call an action generator which sends an AJAX request. I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious to make dispatching an action inside the submit function easier.

```
class AddressForm extends Component {

renderContent() {
    return formFields.map(({ name, label }) => (
        <Field 
            key={name}
            name={name}
            label={label}
            type='text'
            component={FormField}
        />
        )
    );
};

render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
            {this.renderContent()}
            <button type="submit">Next</button>
        </form>
    );
};
};

const validate = (values) => {
const errors = {};

errors.email = validateEmail(values.email || '');

formFields.forEach(({ name }) => {
    if (!values[name]) errors[name] = 'Please provide a value';
});

return errors;
};

const myReduxForm = reduxForm({
   validate,
   form: 'addressForm'
})(AddressForm);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
   onSubmit: data => dispatch(submitForm(data, ownProps.history))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)
(withRouter(myReduxForm));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, instead of connecting, you can use the `handleSubmit` prop inside your component. It allows you to supply a callback with three arguments: values, dispatch and props. So you can do something like:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit((values,dispatch,{submitForm})=> dispatch(submitForm(values)))} />
```

Comment: Np, please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.